# Hadoop Yarn Daemons Stop Running

Tags: hadoop, daemon, resourcemanager

Running start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh followed by jps gives the following output:

```
8227 ResourceManager
8328 NodeManager
7804 NameNode
8366 Jps
8077 SecondaryNameNode
7901 DataNode
```

If I run jps about 5 seconds later, the ouput is:

```
7804 NameNode
8473 Jps
8077 SecondaryNameNode
7901 DataNode
```

The two yarn daemons (ResourceManager and NodeManager) stop working for some reasons. Any idea as to why this may happen?

Comment: Like jkbkot said below, check the logs, usually the reasons are obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically happens when there are problems starting up the services. It could be a lot of things - missing configuration, permission issues, etc.

You'll have to inspect the logs of ResourceManager and NodeManager for more details.

Comment: Yea, it was alot of different things. Specifically, I had to modify the yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml config files.

Comment: @Olshansk could you mention which properties you had to modify?

Comment: Unfortunately this was so long ago that I really can't remember. If I recall, it had to do with the total amount of memory I was allocating for the whole cluster, combined with the number of mappers / reducers, and the min/max memory for each mapper and reducer.

Let me know if you're still stuck. I can probably dig this project up and look and my git history.